# Hide the console window(log4net) under Release Build

Tags: c#, log4net, sharpdevelop

I am using `SharpDevelop` as a component in my application, but the `log4net` console window always appears whether I build it under the `Release` or `Debug` configuration.

How do I hide it as `SharpDevelop` do under the Release configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Change the Output Type on your project so it is a Windows Application instead of a Console Application. The console window only appears when you build your application as a console application.

If you are using SharpDevelop to build your application, select the project in the Projects window, right click select Properties, then change the Output Type drop down list.